# Issue with Rest and Populate on a Media Field in Strapi

Tags: strapi

I have a media field in Strapi that contains seven images, but I only want to retrieve the first two images using Rest and Populate. Currently, I’m able to retrieve all seven images in an array, but I only need the first two.

Here’s an example of my current query using qs.stringify:

```js
const PopulaireDataQuery = qs.stringify(
  {
    populate: {
      Images: {
        fields: ['url', 'formats'],
      },
    },
  },
  {
    encodeValuesOnly: true,
  }
);
```

Can anyone suggest how I can modify this query to retrieve only the first two images using Rest and Populate?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `pagination` parameter in your query:

```js
const PopulaireDataQuery = qs.stringify(
  {
    pagination: {
      limit: 2,
    },
    populate: {
      Images: {
        fields: ["url", "formats"],
      },
    },
  },
  {
    encodeValuesOnly: true,
  }
);
```

More info: https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/api/rest/sort-pagination#pagination-by-offset

Comment: Nooo, Pagination will limite the number of entries and not the number of images inside the media fields